# CommonJS require vs. ES6 import discrepancy

Tags: reactjs, commonjs, typeform

So, I am new to React. Apologies if I am missing something obvious, I'm wrestling with a weird issue with my ES6 imports.

I'm using the [`@typeform/embed`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typeform/embed) module (0.12.1), which oddly links to a GitHub repo on npm but that repo doesn't exist. So I haven't been able to look into potentially related issues.

Anyways, whenever I do the following:

`import typeformEmbed from '@typeform/embed'`

My text editor shows that the type of `typeformEmbed` is a string, and when I go to invoke a function on it, it is always `undefined`. Gives me the 'ole cannot invoke property X on undefined TypeError. It almost looks as if it is trying to import the `README`?

But, then I opened up my Node REPL and could write:

`const typeformEmbed = require('@typeform/embed')`

and it works like a charm.

Is there some discrepancy between the two that I am missing?

**Edit:** I know that this question is pretty text-heavy, let me know if there is crucial information that I'm missing. I should mention that I built this project with `create-react-app`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import * as typeformEmbed from '@typeform/embed';


const popUpHandler = () => {     

typeformEmbed.makePopup(
  'https://admin.typeform.com/to/PlBzgL',
  {
     mode: 'drawer_left',
     autoOpen: true,
     autoClose: 3,
     hideScrollbars: true,
     onSubmit: function () {
       console.log('Typeform successfully submitted')
  }
 }
)}
```

Should work for you

Comment: Why? In their README they just import it directly, I guess assuming that the entrypoint file is using the default export syntax? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typeform/embed#usage

Comment: The import in their example doesn't work!  import * as typeformEmbed basically says to 'import everything from the library and alias it as typeformEmbed so you can invoke the functions via the alias'

Comment: Interesting, I guess that is the behavior that `require` will do by default?

Comment: But anyways, will drop them a note that they need to patch up the documentation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: const typeformEmbed = require('@typeform/embed'); is the same as what I showed for ES6.